# Shader models, when to use "ps_4_0_level_9_x" instead of "ps_4_0"

Tags: directx, monogame, hlsl

I've made a very simple post processing shader for my 2D game. It produces scanlines by dimming every other line. For this I use the position of the pixel on the screen.

When using `ps_4_0_level_9_3`, I receive the message:

`shader model ps_4_0 feature level_9_3 doesn’t allow reading from position semantics`

So I switched to just `ps_4_0` and things work fine. I probably won't be using any advanced shaders in my 2D game.

My questions are:

1. By setting the pixel shader to 4_0 only, what impact does that have for my game (if any) - is it a mistake to 'downgrade' the pixelshader?
2. How do I know what pixelshader version to use? I found this: [Direct3D featurelevels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) but I'm unsure when to use what shader? Is there a list like "for windows use this", "for mobile this" or is it, use the lowest version that supports the feature you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you do want to use the lowest level you possibly can. The lower the level, the wider the range of hardware that your game supports, and the more people that can play (and buy) your game.

That said, as you're using DX10/11 already, you're already targeting markets that actually use Vista and up, which mostly coincide with the markets that have DX10-level hardware or better. Targeting SM 5.1 is probably a mistake, but 4.0 is likely just fine.

Given that DX9-level hardware is getting rare for anyone running Vista up these days, I tend to just stick with shader model 4.0 as a minimum. That said, you may feel differently. At [least one source indicates that 20% of gamers can't run DX10 either due to hardware or OS](http://hwstats.unity3d.com/pc/gpu.html), though it doesn't qualify that with market demographics.

There are markets where DX9 is sadly still the API of choice, but those are markets you're very unlikely to have any luck in for a variety of non-technical reasons (e.g. national laws that make life difficult for foreign games, nationalist loyalty from gamers towards domestic game manufacturers, or wildly different game design preferences than present in the West).

This of course is one of the supposed advantages of GL vs DX. With GL, you can use the latest hardware features even on older Windows versions. The flip side is that the drivers are likely out of date and buggy, so your GL app is likely to generate far more support requests and unhappy customers than a DX version. This is why, for example, the browsers all implement WebGL via a DX layer on Windows rather than just using GL directly. Even when the current drivers are high quality, folks on older Windows OSes are far far more likely to be running out of date drivers, and not even know how to upgrade them.

The out-of-date driver problem also affects DX, though to a far lesser degree. I'd suggest targeting only modern Windows OSes unless you have a very strong reason to indicate that XP users make up a significant portion of your target market, as the cost of targeting XP (in terms of development, testing, support, etc.) is just getting higher and higher as time goes on.

**TL;DR**: lower feature levels will widen your potential audience but probably by an insignificant amount.

Comment: If you require Direct3D Feature Level 10.0 or later, you can safely always use the ``?s_4_0`` profiles. If you support Direct3D Feature Level 9.3, you have to use ``?s_4_0_level_9_3`` profile--this is the shader model required for Windows phone 8.  If you support Direct3D Feature Level 9.1, then you have to use ``?s_4_0_level_9_1`` profile--this was required to support the Surface RT.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, shader model 3.0 is for directx9, 4.0 is for directx10 and 5.0 is used by directx 11. The 4.0_feature_level_9_3 is for dx9 but with some features from dx10.